# QGIS Experimental CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, mobile

From the Play Store I have installed QGIS Experimental on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2. All seems to work fine but I cannot set the coordinate reference system.

From the SETTINGS menu I then select OPTIONS then CRS.

Under section for new layers I select USE A DEFAULT CRS but after clicking search icon NO list of world CRS are displayed for selection.
I want to use EPSG:27700 - OSGB1936.

Have done this without any problem on my desktop QGIS 2.18